# Get the :before value of an element with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="one">This is a piece of content</div>
```

and this CSS:

```
.one:before{
   content: 'done';
}
```

How can I `console.log` this `content` value with jQuery?

Comment: pseudo selector are not supported by jQuery as they are not part of the DOM

Comment: you want to get the value inside `<div class="one"></div>`??

Comment: http://davidwalsh.name/pseudo-element

Comment: View this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rpqutLfb/